# CNN for 3D image segmentation with different size

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am working on 3D image segmentation task, but the length of z-axis is different in every image. For the convolution neural networks, I think the length should be same in all images. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're working with, but you should transform your input before passing it through your network (e.g. in a data loader). In this case, one of the transforms should be a resize operation (to the appropriate dimensions).

https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html

Comment: i know about resize option. but its not x-axis or y-axis, its time axis, or you can say that slice axis. I don't think resize is the right option

Comment: If you don't resize to the appropriate shape, your network won't accept the input.

Comment: even i prediction, the images are of different time length. so I also need to resize ground truth, which is not the right option

Comment: The network will only accept one shape. If it's a tensor shaped (batch_size, channels, x_dim, y_dim, z_dim), and your z-dim represents time, they should all have the same 'duration'.

Comment: i believe the same, but its not in my hand. i am thinking to make z-axis of same duration, then in prediction revert back to the original duration for the mask. But I am looking for the right package to do this task. Any idea

Comment: Maybe you should give a little more info? Maybe you want to look into recurrent (convolutional) neural nets?

Comment: I am using 3D unet for segmentation task

Comment: 3D-UNet takes volumetric images, not time series of 2D-images.  You could process single images (2D-unet) and calculate features on the segmentations if you’re interested in evolution? Or use a recurrent conv net to predict future images (I think)?